# Exception: Invalid Cast after 2 years

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, casting, visual-studio-2005

My VS2005 web application was working fine for the last two years. But today it suddenly started throwing exception of Invalid Cast.

My code is:

```
int DistID = (int) this.Session["DISTRIBUTOR_ID"];
```

This line worked fine for more than two years.

But now it suddenly started throwing exception of invalid cast. I checked in debug mode

```
this.Session["DISTRIBUTOR_ID"]
```

had valid int value of 1234.

I solved the problem by changing my code to:

```
int DistID = Convert.ToInt32(this.Session["DISTRIBUTOR_ID"]);
```

But my boss asked me why this error occurred all of a sudden.

Can anyone answer this question?

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: @Ignacio This looks a hell of a lot like C#.

Comment: @Etienne: What can I say, the tags threw me. Especially that worthless "invalid" tag.

Answer (score 4):

Convert.ToInt32() function call the parsing function internally but with the first implementation you are using boxing and unboxing.
the value in the session should be an integer type when it is assigned.

Comment: Thanks HusseinX for your quick answer. Now I get the exact location where I did wrong. Few days ago I change my code.  this.Session.Add("DISTRIBUTOR_ID", Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["DISTRIBUTOR_ID"]); to  this.Session.Add("DISTRIBUTOR_ID", dt.Rows[0]["DISTRIBUTOR_ID"].ToString()); Which cause the exception. Thank you again.